# Not getting output of uima ruta

Tags: apache, uima, ruta

I am working on UIMA Ruta using eclipse, in which I created annotators to fetch the text, the annotators are highlighting the required text, but the output files created by Ruta(following rules of annotator) is of the XML format. I want to know how to produce the output of annotators in a separate text file.

I tried to get the output using Ruta query but the result is shown in new popped up window which doesn't save the output, referring to the docs, got to know that I am supposed to save the output manually

Want to get the text file in which only the output of annotators is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Since UIMA Ruta is part of the Apache UIMA text processing framework, in order to save the created annotations with Ruta separately, you'll need to fetch the desired annotations from Ruta generated output with UIMA.

A good starting point with UIMA can be found [here](https://uima.apache.org/doc-uima-annotator.html)

Basically, once you have the jCas, the required annotations can be extracted with:

```
Collection<YourAnnotationType> annotations = JCasUtil.select(jCas, YourAnnotationType.class);
```

From here on, the `annotations` (along with their features) can be saved to an external CSV file.